# How to pass context into custom dialogs?

Tags: node.js, electron

So in certain pages I want a dialog/modal to popup and display some custom HTML depending on the circumstances, the easiest thing I came up with was to create a *brand new* `BrowserWindow` and load in the respective `popup.html` depending on the case. I need some help doing a few things though.

First: I can't seem to find any way to *pass in* some context into the browser window, I've tried the following:

```
let window = new electron.remote.BrowserWindow({...});
let context = "sample context";
window.webContents.executeJavaScript(`electron.remote.getCurrentWindow().context = ${context};`);
window.context = context;
```

And in the `popup.html`'s script, it can't access:

```
electron.remote.getCurrentWindow().context;
window.context;
document.context;
```

as they all return undefined.

Also in the testing of trying to find a way to pass in some context, I found I can't figure out how to access the TOP window. 
For example if the main window opens a dialog, and it opens a dialog, how does the main window get the window thats displays ON-TOP of all the other windows? As `electron.remote.getCurrentWindow()` just returns the window that the script's part of not the top-level window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while I've figured out how to do what I wanted.

## Step 1:

In the js file that loads the dialog/popup you need:

```js
    const electron = require('electron'), path = require('path');
    let window = new electron.remote.BrowserWindow({...});
    let context = "sample context";
    window.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "./file.html"),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    })).then(function(){
        window.webContents.send('store-data', context);
        window.show();
    })
    electron.ipcRenderer.on("callback", (event,val) => {
        window.destroy();
        // val is whatever the dialog sent back.
    });
```

## Step 2:

In the dialog/popup's js file you'd need:

```js
    const electron = require('electron'), ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;
    let callback = function (value) {
        electron.remote.getCurrentWindow().getParentWindow().webContents.send('callback',value);
    };
    ipcRenderer.on('store-data', function (event, context) {
        console.log(context)//"sample context"
    });
    //Do whatever. And when you want to close the dialog/popup or send back input, just call callback(...);
```